# Word Matching in a Sentence in a Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to lookup few values in a sentence in a cell.

Example:

Sheet 1 has the below data

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
     <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>No 23, New Avenue, Texas</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>No 18, 4th Cross Road, Florida</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Sheet 2 has the below data

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
     <th>Location</th>
    <th>Code</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Texas</td>
    <td>44</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Florida</td>
    <td>45</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the code from sheet 2 to be pasted in sheet 1 based on the address column in sheet 1.  I know to VLOOKUP but it works for whole words only but I want to take a particular word in the sheet 2 and search for it sheet 1.  The html codes are just for table representation.  This is a excel data. Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In sheet1, C2:

[image]

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]"),Sheet2!A:A,0))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have tried something but not sure how to recursively match each cel value in the range. =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1, " "&Sheet1!E7&" ")),Sheet2!$B$1,"Not Matching")  Please help.

Comment: It's not close to my suggestion to be honest =)

Answer (score 0):

I used Tables and structured references instead of sheets, but you can change the addressing method to regular addresses if you prefer.

```
=VLOOKUP(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE([@Address]," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)),Table2,2,FALSE)
```

I assumed the `Location` would always be the last word in the Address string.  The formula for that extraction is the  `TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE([@Address]," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))` which we use for `lookup_value` in the `VLOOKUP` formula.

[image]